# not displaying data from parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

finally got past all the errors, but i'm still not able to see data on my UITableView from universityEnrolledName(column) in the University class within Parse.

I think it has to do with my query

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "University")
    query.whereKey("univeristyEnrolledName", equalTo:"UCSD")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
              for object in objects {
                println("The value of object.objectId is ( object.objectId)")
                self.funlists.append("\(object.objectId)")
              }
              self.uiTableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            println("value of object is messed")
              // Log details of the failure
           // NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error!, error!.userInfo!)
          }
      }
```

been stuck on this for more than a few days now, any ideas?

Comment: you missed a step. once you retrieve data reload the table view.

Comment: @VivekMolkar thanks, fixed this error but still no data is displaying, any other possible reasons as to why this is occurring? thanks I appreciate the help

Comment: make sure you reload tableview on main thread. use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.uiTableView.reloadData()
})` this is the one reason I feel may cause some problem

Comment: @VivekMolkar, just implemented the reload tableview on the main thread, but still no data is displaying on the table, it just remains blank. My (numberOfSectionsInTableView method and tableView numberOfRowsInSection method are the same as shown below)... Thanks again

Comment: are you sure delegate methods are getting hit?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update your rows.

```
if let objects = objects {
    var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]
    for object in objects {
        println("The value of object.objectId is ( object.objectId)")
        self.funlists.append("\(object.objectId)")
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(row: self.funlists.count - 1, section: 0))
    }
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, rowAnimation: .Default)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement your data array to table view

```
       if let objects = objects {
          for object in objects {
            println("The value of object.objectId is ( object.objectId)")
            self.funlists.append("\(object.objectId)")
          }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

//////////////

```
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)->Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int {

        return self.funlists.count;
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell;

            cell.textLabel?.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, on the line where i reload the data, i'm getting the error 'Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments' any idea how to fix this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: tableView supposed to be your tableView instance in your project, and check if it is delegated from super view. like:  myTableView.delegate = self in your ViewController

Comment: thanks, even after fixing this error however data is still not displaying, any other idea possibly as to why nothing is displaying on the UITableView?

Comment: Did you add a register class for table cell where you delegate your tableView? like :   tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")